# What happens if you manually update a .CSS file when a .SCSS/.SASS file is in use?

Tags: css, sass, codekit

I've got the below setup:

- Brackets IDE
- CodeKit for compiling SASS/SCSS into CSS
- CloudMounter to mount a live copy of a Wordpress site via FTP (it also auto updates the server's files with any changes I make to the mounted version).

Here's how it works:

1. Add SCSS styling into .SCSS file
2. Save SCSS file
3. CodeKit auto compiles into CSS file, and stores on Local/mounted drive.
4. CloudMounter picks up the change and auto uploads it to server where Wordpress site is hosted.

Probably not the most efficient workflow but I'm quite impressed with what I've managed to pull off.

My question is: What happens if one of the other people in my office directly FTPs onto the server and makes an edit to the .CSS file instead of using the above method to add SCSS instead?

Will this break the compiler? When I update the SCSS file in the future, will this overwrite/ignore the new custom CSS?

I'd rather like to keep myself as the only developer who uses SCSS instead of having to train the other people in the office.

Comment: Mhm scss is not that complicated and has many advantages. It looks very close to css.. so give your colleagues a chance! :)

Comment: I have no doubt that they'll be able to do it, but they seem very set in their ways, So I wouldn't want to try and force a change upon them if they didn't want to. But thanks for your kind words :)

Comment: If someone updates the CSS file on the server (always a bad idea, don't do live updates) those changes **will get overwritten**. Those changes will not affect the compiler. The compiler is on your local machine. It simply converts your SASS to CSS and creates a new file that overwrites the old file every time. Then that file is copied to the server and overwrites the file on the server.

Comment: Simple solution. Dont allow anyone to update the CSS on the server except you. If they persist, give them sole responsibility for the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DON'T! It will be very hard to maintain what you edited and when you reload the Wordpress site you will lose the edits to the compiled CSS file (pure assumption). If you ABSOLUTELY have to just put the extra CSS you want to add or want your coworkers to add in separate CSS files that AREN'T SCSS/SASS.

SCSS compiles to CSS, that would be like writing software in C++ and then editing the compiled object files or writing software in Java and then editing the byte code. It is just very backwards and not ideal.

By doing what you said you wanted to do you are doing something that is not not advised. SCSS is neat because it allows you to short hand a bunch of stuff and saves you typing and annoying syntax and lets you use variables which plain CSS doesn't allow. Adding plain CSS to a mainly SCSS styled app isn't bad, but I suggest you put all your additional CSS in a separate file so that it is clear what the compiled CSS from SCSS is and what the new CSS you used is.

For the most part SCSS can almost be used Exactly like CSS as far as I know and its worth learning.

Comment: So would you reccomend using a separate stylesheet that is inserted into the main style.scss using @import?

Comment: That seems like a viable option. Whatever the include pipeline is, I typically use a application.scss and import/include everything there.

Comment: @BillyFerguson I'm sorry but I'm not following you on the first part of the third paragraph, _"what you said you wanted to do you are doing something that is not not advised."_ What exactly are you referring to that is _not advised_?

Comment: @hungerstar He's simply saying that that's not what people do. People don't advise it as it'll just get overwritten. The same as what you said in the comment. :)

Comment: Okay, a lot of that last paragraph is a bit incoherent and was having trouble understanding what he was saying. Like, _"put all your additional CSS in a separate file so that it is clear what the compiled CSS from SCSS is"_. If you're using SCSS put all your CSS in a `.scss` files. If you want to modularize them and create multiple files like `_reset.scss`, `_typography.scss` and `_variables.scss` and then combine them in a master file like `script.scss` using `@import 'reset.scss` etc. Which I think he was getting at.

Comment: @hungerstar OP wanted to modify the CSS file generated from the SCSS. I was saying if he MUST use CSS don't edit the CSS generated from SCSS because then he won't know which styling was CSS generated from SCSS and which styling was from the modifications/additions of his own CSS to the CSS generated from the SCSS.

Comment: I understood the overwrite issue. Just the way it's worded was a little unclear for me. Simple file compare would tell you what is different between the two files and you'd know what co-workers have added.

Comment: You're missing my point. OP wasn't talking about adding CSS to an SCSS file. OP was talking about adding CSS to the CSS file generated from SCSS. Also he mentions using ftp to update the file so I'm assuming that there would be no way to perform the "simple file diff" @hungerstar mentioned.

Comment: LOLz, I'm not missing the point. I totally understand that the OP was talking about co-workers updating the CSS file (on the server) that the OP had generated from SCSS and uploaded to the server. You can easily pull down that file and compare, not that you'd have to, but an option. All this squabble from a request for clarification on prose, aye yai yai.

Comment: You did it to yourself!